# Pivot Table vs Parent_ID for 1-Many Relation

Tags: database, database-design

In a general one-to-many (parent-to-child) relationship, is there a significant efficiency difference between (a) putting parent_id in the child table and (b) using a pivot table of only parent_id, child_id?

NOTE: Assume Oracle if necessary, otherwise answer using a general RDBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by `PIVOT` table you mean a `many-to-many` link table, then no, it will only hamper performance.

You should keep `parent_id` in the child table.

The `many-to-many` link table takes an extra `JOIN` and therefore is less efficient.

Compare the following queries:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    child_table c
JOIN    child_to_parent cp
ON      cp.child = c.id
JOIN    parent p
ON      p.id = cp.parent
WHERE   c.property = 'some_property'
```

and this one:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    child_table c
JOIN    parent p
ON      p.id = c.parent
WHERE   c.property = 'some_property'
```

The latter one is one `JOIN` shorter and more efficient.

The only possible exception to that rule is that you run these queries often:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    child_table c
JOIN    parent_table p
ON      p.id = c.parent
WHERE   c.id IN (id1, id2, ...)
```

, i. e. you know the `id`'s of the child rows beforehand.

This may be useful if you use natural keys for your `child_table`.

In this case yes, the `child_to_parent` link table will be more efficient, since you can just replace it with the following query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    child_to_parent cp
JOIN    parent_table p
ON      p.id = cp.parent
WHERE   cp.child IN (id1, id2, ...)
```

and `child_to_parent` will be always less or equal in size to `child_table`, and hence more efficient.

However, in `Oracle` you can achieve just the same result creating a composite index on `child_table (id, parent_id)`.

Since `Oracle` does not index `NULL`'s, this index will be just like your `child_to_parent` table, but without the table itself and implied maintenance overhead.

In other systems (which index `NULL`'s), the index may be less efficient than a dedicated table, especially if you have lots of `NULL` parents.